# What is ng-binding for in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am an AngularJS newbie and trying to figure out what `class=ng-binding` does in this example:

```
<label ng-dblclick="editTodo(todo)" class="ng-binding">fghfgh</label>
```

I found it here:

```
http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/
```

I use Chrome and developer tools. Is this an angular keyword? I could not find it in the manual (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`class="ng-binding"` is used internally by Angular.  For example, looking at the [`ngBind` source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ed885984d58d344350ae267f51e8096bb6bea6/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js) we find this line that adds the class and associates the binding with it using [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
 element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBind);
```

That's why this line of Angular source (noting the double curlys on `{{todo.title}}` result in an `ngBind`):

```
<label ng-dblclick="editTodo(todo)">{{todo.title}}</label>
```

Is translated into what you see in the debugger:

```
<label ng-dblclick="editTodo(todo)" class="ng-binding">fghfgh</label>
```

So `class="ng-binding"` isn't something you should use.  You'll find Angular frequently uses classes, comments and other markers- so you'll often see this kind of change between the original html and the Angular processed results.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why angular adds the ng-binding class

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/css-styling):

> `ng-binding`
>
> Usage: angular applies this class to any element that is attached to a
>   data binding, via ng-bind or {{}} curly braces, for example. (see
>   [databinding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) guide)

So the class `ng-binding` is applied by angular dynamically, for the compiler to understand that, element has a data binding associated with it.

As a developer we don't have to worry about that unless we apply some styles to these classes.